# errors argument in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

why i'm getting this error ?

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Http\Request::Illuminate\Foundation\Providers{closure}() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\projek_ppob\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php on line 114

this is the controller

```
public function register()
    {
        return view('user.register');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //melakukan validasi data
        $request->validate($request, [
            'nama' => 'required',
            'nik' => 'required',
            'tgllahir' => 'required',
            'telepon' => 'required',
            'alamat' => 'required',
            'pin' => 'required',
            'foto' => 'required|image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg',
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('image');
        $image->storeAs('public/assets/img/foto_pelanggan', $image->hashName());

        $blog = LoginModel::create([
            'nama'   => $request->nama,
            'nik'     => $request->nik,
            'tgllahir'   => $request->tgllahir,
            'telepon'   => $request->telepon,
            'alamat'   => $request->alamat,
            'pin'   => $request->pin,
            'image'     => $image->hashName(),
        ]);

        if($blog){
            //redirect dengan pesan sukses
            return redirect()->route('blog.index')->with(['success' => 'Data Berhasil Disimpan!']);
        }else{
            //redirect dengan pesan error
            return redirect()->route('blog.index')->with(['error' => 'Data Gagal Disimpan!']);
        }
```

this is form

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form" action="{{ route('store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

this is routes

```
Route::get('/register', [App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class, 'register'])->name('register');
Route::post('/register/store', [App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
```

and this is the models

```
protected $table = 'pelanggan';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nama',
        'nik',
        'tgllahir',
        'telepon',
        'pin',
        'alamat',
        'foto',
    ];
```

Comment: Please show us line 114 in some context.

Comment: How did you solve this issue??